# How to invoke Eclipse from POSTMAN in WindowsOS?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, selenium-chromedriver, postman

I am automating E-2-E REST API execution using POSTMAN.
In the middle of API execution, an email OTP is sent. That email OTP value is needed to be captured and used in making further API calls.

I am using a free online junk email web application to receive such OTP emails. I have created a Selenium-JAVA script using Eclipse to connect to that online email domain through (java.net.HttpURLConnection) and then running Selenium script to play inside that free junk email web application to capture the email OTP.

I am looking at ways how POSTMAN can invoke Eclipse and run that Selenium script which filters out email OTP. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Forget about Postman, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest

Why to over engineer a simple requirement just use google API to read emails , and validate that . Or use any other mail services that have Api or interaction.

Postman works with apis you cannot interact with eclipse unless it has some apis to do so , and more over eclipse is an IDE not runner

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I am not specifically inclined to use Google API. Yes, working with the APIs would be an easy and effective way to solve this scenario but I don't have API info about that free junk email service- so couldn't include it in my POSTMAN REST API calls. Hence, the only way forward I figured out was through filtering out the content with Selenium. Thus such requirement arose.